# How to display A&amp;B to A&B in axlsx?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, xlsx, axlsx

I tried to export excel in my rails application used axlsx gem, but I can not display the `&amp;` code to `&` in excel.

How can I do it ? Welcome for any answer. Thanks!

Comment: I have resolved , I use:


striped_content = ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(content)  and
HTMLEntities.new.decode(striped_content)

Comment: If you have resolved your problem, You can answer your question and mark it as the correct answer.